# Нужна ли запятая перед первым тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Ярославская бабушка прислала пятнадцать тысяч, чтобы купить имение на ее имя, – нам она не верит, – а этих денег не хватило бы даже процент заплатить. (А.Чехов. Вишневый сад)

Запятая после "имя" поставлена для симметрии или для того, чтобы закрыть придаточное? Но вроде бы вставка относится к нему, и тогда запятая перед первым тире не нужна, а запятая перед вторым тире закрывала бы придаточное и разделяла части в сложносочиненном предложении.